jqgrid Shows No Records even after adding a row
I am incorporating new rows into jqGrid utilizing the AddRowData method. There have been instances where it displays "No records" alongside the newly added records, as illustrated in the image below. Please refer to the code I am using to add the new row. This issue occurs intermittently. Is there a solution available?
Issue Image
let Data = [{
     
     "DESC": "SPA"
 }];
 let rowCount = $("#jqGrid").getGridParam("reccount");
 if (rowCount == 0)
     jQuery("#jqGrid").addRowData(rowCount, Data);
 else
     jQuery("#jqGrid").addRowData(rowCount, Data, "last");


Which version of jqGrid is used?

Guriddo jqGrid JS - v5.8.7 -
